# how to throw new Error in axios when response.data.code is not 200

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using an old API.
Which responds to every call with 200 OK.

```json
{
    "msg": "invalid",
    "result": null,
    "code": 400
}
```

I need to trow an error somehow. So the catch block can handle it.

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    if (response.data.code < 200 || response.data.code > 399) Promise.reject(response.data.msg);
    return response;
  },
  (error) =>
    Promise.reject(
      (error.response && error.response.msg) || "مشکلی پیش امده است"
    )
);
```

Comment: throwing an error in the response will not go into the error block.

Answer (score 0):

return `Promise.reject(<message>)`

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    if (response.data.code < 200 || response.data.code > 399) return Promise.reject(response.data.msg);
    return response;
  },
  (error) =>
    Promise.reject(
      (error.response && error.response.msg) || "مشکلی پیش امده است"
    )
);
```